# why am I getting "Access violation" writing location?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c-strings, strtok, string-literals

I am trying to use `strtok` to get a string with `\0` instead of spaces for replacing the `\0` with `#` so I am using `strtok` for that. but I am getting -  Access violation writing location
in this line - `char* word = strtok(stringOfNumberSign, delimiters);`

```
char* addNumberSignToString(char* stringOfNumberSign)
{
    int numOfWords = 0;
    char* delimiters = " ";
    char* word = strtok(stringOfNumberSign, delimiters);
    while (word)
    {   
        numOfWords++;
        word = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }

    return stringOfNumberSign;
}

int main()

{
    char* stringForNumberSign = "welcome to hello world";
    char* result;
    result = addNumberSignToString(stringForNumberSign);
    printf("%s", result);
}
```

Comment: why we have to guess how is declared and initialized stringOfNumberSign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strtok` changes the passed string.

From the C Standard (7.23.5.8 The strtok function)

> 4 The strtok function then searches from there for a character that is
> contained in the current separator string. If no such character is
> found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to
> by s1, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null pointer.
> **If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character, which terminates the current token.** The strtok function saves a
> pointer to the following character, from which the next search for a
> token will start.

However you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

And you are trying to change a string literal

```
char* stringForNumberSign = "welcome to hello world";
//...
result = addNumberSignToString(stringForNumberSign);
```

At least you should use a character array instead of the string literal

```
char stringForNumberSign[] = "welcome to hello world";
```

Pay attention to that your function as is does not make a sense.